# Thunderbird changes the size of attachment

Tags: email, thunderbird, attachments

I want to send an email with an attached pdf file using Thunderbird. The file is about 15~16MB, but Thunderbird shows it as having 21MB:

[image]

This prevents the mail to be sent:

[image]

Any ideas what can be happening and how to solve it?

Thanks for any hint!!

(I know about file links, I just cannot use them for this particular issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong here. Attachments are encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). With headers etc. this adds about 33-37% to the original file size.

When you create a message you see original sizes of attachments; but global size limit later applies to the whole message, *encoded* attachment(s) included.

This limit you see comes from your e-mail server. Compare [*How can I send a large attachment?*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-can-i-send-large-attachment)

You can:

- Compress the file
- or/and split it into parts and send separately.
- Use account on a different server (with higher limit) and hope it won't hit a lower limit somewhere on its way to the recipient (it may pass through several mail transfer agents, then there's a final server). The best case is when you and the recipient use the same server and its limit is high enough for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Then I assume that there's nothing to be done here and the actual maximum size of attachments is some 14MB?

Comment: For sufficiently long strings, Base64 encoding closely approaches only 1/3 larger than than the decoded form (33.3...% larger, not 37% larger). There are headers and final padding which extend the length of short messages enough to throw off that number, but in general, base64 means each three bytes of input turn into four bytes of output, making the message 1/3 longer. However, MIME messages in general have some overhead beyond just the character encoding, which is why the final message size is more than 4/3 the size of the attachment.

Comment: @CBHacking Is this to provide the message with checksum bytes? 3 Bytes message + 1 Byte check/something?

Comment: Base64 encoding for binary (and sometimes Quoted Printable encoding for text) are used because email systems are designed for ASCII (which only uses 7 bits) and not guaranteed to be "8-bit clean"; they may not correctly handle characters that have the most-significant bit set. Since half of all possible bytes have this bit set, binary files (like PDFs) must be converted to an equivalent representation that uses a limited character set, which means it needs more characters to store the same amount of data (it's basically the reverse of compression). Unicode text can have the same problem.

Comment: @CBHacking Thank you. I modified this "37%" part a little.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. Well, thanks! I learned something new today :)